# Python: SocketServer has no socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, socketserver

I want to use a Python socketserver to wait for a message, but to time out periodically and do some other processing.  As far as I can tell, the following code should work, but the call to handle_request() throws an AttributeError exception, complaining that MyTCPServer object has no attribute 'socket'.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import socketserver

class SingleTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    # One instance per connection.  Override handle(self) to customize action.
    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the client connection
        data = self.request.recv(1024)  # clip input at 1Kb
        print ("Received data: " + data.decode())
        self.request.close()

class MyTCPServer(socketserver.BaseServer):

    def __init__(self, serverAddress, handler):
        super().__init__(serverAddress, handler)

    def handle_timeout(self):
        print ("No message received in {0} seconds".format(self.timeout))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("SocketServerWithTimeout.py")
    tcpServer = MyTCPServer(("127.0.0.1", 5006), SingleTCPHandler)
    tcpServer.timeout = 5

    loopCount = 0
    while loopCount < 5:
        tcpServer.handle_request()
        print ("Back from handle_request")
        loopCount = loopCount + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socketserver.BaseServer` is a common base class for both UDP and TCP servers.

Your code will work if your server inherits instead from `socketserver.TCPServer`.

Comment: Drat.  I knew it would be something that would make me look like an idiot.

Thanks very much!

Comment: It doesn't make you look like an idiot. It makes you look like a programmer who is learning. I've been at it nearly fifty years and I'm still making mistakes, so don't feel too bad!